# Configure ISAPI redirector: worker propreties for IIS and Liferay

Tags: iis, tomcat, isapi, liferay

I Asked this question on stackOverflow, i didn't get any answers sorry if the questions is somehow duplicated, any way :

---

we have fronted Liferay tomcat server with IIS , and we used ISAPI tomcat redirector for that ,everything works just fine. the problem is that We need to map a specific Domain name to a specific URL on Liferay:

1. workers.properties :

> worker.mydomain_com.port=8014
>
> worker.mydomain_com.host=127.0.0.1
>
> worker.mydomain_com=ajp13

1. uriworkermap.properties

> /mydomain.com/=mydomain_com
>
> /www.mydomain.com=mydomain_com
>
> /www.mydomain.com/*=mydomain_com

This configuration will map www.mydomain.com to localhost:xxxx . what i want is how to configure the worker mydomain_com so it can be mapped to localhost:xxxx/web/organiation. I searched for worker.mydomain.options but there is no configuration for the uri, is there any way to do ? Thanks